# How to get shell using curl post request in kubernetes?

Tags: bash, docker, curl, kubernetes, devops

I am creating a pod spec using json which when run will give me a shell on the underlying node as shown below.

```
overrides=$(cat <<EOF
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "admin-shell"
    },
    "spec": {
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "admin-shell",
          "securityContext": {
          "privileged": true
          },
          "image": "alpine:latest",
          "args": ["chroot", "/kdet", "/bin/bash"],
          "stdin": true,
          "stdinOnce": true,
          "tty": true,
          "volumeMounts": [{
            "name": "kdet",
            "mountPath": "/kdet"
          }]
      }],
      "volumes": [{
        "name": "kdet",
        "hostPath": {
          "path": "/",
          "type": "Directory"
        }
      }]        
    }
}
EOF
)

kubectl run --image alpine:latest --rm --restart=Never --overrides="$foo" -ti test
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
[root@admin-shell /]# exit
exit
pod "admin-shell" deleted
```

However, when I try to launch the pod using curl with the config saved in api.json, the pod is being created, however I don't get the shell as I got in the previous step.

```
>curl -k $APISERVER/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods \
-XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d@api.json \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2900    0  2250  100   650  13005   3757 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16763

{
  "phase": "Pending",
  "qosClass": "BestEffort"
}
```

Can you please help me how can I get the shell using curl?

Comment: That seems like a significant security issue if that were allowed.  Do you have more direct access to the node?

Comment: Hi @David, Yes I do have direct access. However, I am writing this to check the if I can perform the same using curl.

Comment: Curl usually makes a single (non-interactive) HTTP request; it's not the tool I'd pick for this.  ssh directly to the node bypassing the Kubernetes API would be a better choice here.